# How user will login with dynamically created subdomain php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have developed a web application, it allows user to create their own sub-domain and they can access my web application.

I have done creating sub domains,separate database using cpanel helper function.

All of my main files are present in **/public_html/myapplication** folder and all sub domains created folder under **/public_html/subdomains/abc**, /public_html/subdomains/xyz folder.

After user creating the subdomain (abc.example.com), they can access with the created sub-domain link. But ***how can they login into my application.***

Now my problem is "When sub-domains are created, there is always a empty folder. Once user entered the sub-domain it returns "INDEX OF -- LIST OF FILES" instead of my web application login screen from /public_html/myapplication with appropriate user database login.

When user entered the sub-domain, it should appear the login screen and they entered their details, it should check with appropriate sub-domain database (i.e each sub domain have one database) and login into the web application which is located **/public_html/myapplication** folder.

There is no need to copy all my application files to each subdomains.

My expect is to create like teamwork.com, hiveage.com

Please help to achieve this.

Comment: use htaccess to redirect requests to the sub domain to appropriate files in the application.

Comment: I don't know how to redirect.

Comment: I don't think anybody can help you unless they know which url needs to be redirected to where. Here is a tutorial on [URL Rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create the subdomains. You can achieve the desired result using:

1. `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` in your .htaccess file
2. Wildcard DNS entry `*.yourdomain.com`
3. ServerAlias in your virtual host configuration file

1) In your `.htaccess` file in the docroot of your domain, use `RewriteCond` to check that the host is not already `www.` and `RewriteRule` to add the subdomain as the query string.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?subdomain=%1 [L,QSA]
```

2) You can use a wildcard DNS entry to capture all subdomain DNS traffic using `*.yourdomain.com` pointing to your host.

```
*.yourdomain.com     A     0.0.0.0
```

(replace 0.0.0.0 with your server IP address)

3) If you're using [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) you must add a wildcard [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias) to catch all subdomains.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
ServerAlias *.yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot "/public_html/myapplication"
```

Above is just a snippet of the Apache configuration file, normally `httpd.conf` depending on your server setup.

**Edit:** On cPanel and you can skip steps 2 and 3 by creating a wildcard subdomain from within the cPanel GUI.

1. Log in your cPanel.
2. Navigate to the menu Subdomains under Domains section
3. Create a subdomain * pointing it to the necessary folder (public_html)
4. Go to the menu Advanced DNS Zone Editor
5. Make sure that there is an A record for *.yourdomain.com created and pointed to the server IP address
6. Now you will need to wait until the propagation is over

Comment: When I try 1st Step,  I enterted abc.example.com, url changes to example.com/index.php?subdomain=abc . But I don't want like this, I want the url will show the login page of "/public_html/myapplication", it should be linked to it. When other subdomain changes, url will change xyz.example.com same folder should be access. URL will be SEO friendly

Comment: I tried Step 3, I entered abc.example.com, it is not pointing to the document root

Comment: Edited to include cPanel details. I also made a few changes to the .htaccess code. Note 1: The `RewriteRule` currently points to `index.php` with the subdomain name appended in the query string. You need to adjust this as required to work with your code. You mention you need it to show the login page - you will need to change as necessary and handle this within your application. Note 2: if you have existing subdomains setup pointing to a different docroot to your main application this may overrule the wildcard subdomain. You should delete them if not required.